# getChildNodes() returns Text instead of NodeList

Tags: java, xml, matlab, dom, xml-parsing

I'm trying to do XML parsing in MATLAB, which uses JavaSE package org.w3c.dom

I have a xml structure like

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tada>
  <Filters>
    <filter id="1" name="name1" renderType="type1">
      <bool name="par1" value="false"/>
      <bool name="par2" value="false"/>
      <int name="par3" value="200"/>
      <int name="par4" value="1"/>
      <float name="par5" value="2"/>
      <bool name="par6" value="false"/>
      <int name="par7" value="1"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="6" name="name2" renderType="type2">
      <bool name="par1" value="false"/>
      <bool name="par2" value="false"/>
      <int name="par3" value="200"/>
      <int name="par4" value="1"/>
      <float name="par5" value="2"/>
      <bool name="par6" value="false"/>
      <int name="par7" value="1"/>
      <int name="par8" value="1"/>
      <array name="par9" row="2" col="2" >
        5.0162 0.96182
        0.22294 0.96356
      </array>
    </filter>
  </Filters>
</tada>
```

I'm trying to get access for, let say attribute **renderType** of element **filter** with **name="name2"**

I'm trying to do the following

```js
config = xmlread(xmlFileName);

section = config.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName('Filters').item(0);
    
filters = section.getChildNodes();
// filters = section.getElementsByTagName('filter');

for i = 0:filters.getLength()-1
    filter = filters.item(i);
    if strcmp(filter.getAttribute('name'), 'name2')
        filter.setAttribute('renderType', 'graph2D');
    end
end
```

I expect that **filters** should be a *NodeList* (as documentation says http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html?browser=F1help), but it's returned as a *Text* (which contains only white spaces).

If I write

```js
filters = section.getElementsByTagName('filter');
```

then I get desired *NodeList*, but the problem is that this way is unsuitable. Because I need to select nodes by the value of **name** property.

Could you help me? What I do wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML document includes whitespace between the elements. This is considered significant by the XML parser, and when you use the DOM method getChildNodes() it includes both the child elements and the child text nodes containing the whitespace. When processing the child nodes, if you want to ignore the whitespace text nodes you must do so explicitly.

Comment: Thank you. But anyway, shouldn't .getChildNodes() return me some node list? And how can I get the list of elements without specifying the tag name?

Comment: Thank you once more. I understood what you mean. Despite **filters** is not NodeList, I can use .item(...) normally. I just should check the resulting type of a **filter** node.

Comment: I think you might be making the mistake of using "node" and "element" as if they were the same thing.